# FCM Priority vs Delivery Time Clarification Needed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently using the legacy http API to send **data messages** from my server to Android devices connected to certain topics. I have both, time critical and not so critical messaging. However I never have messaging which needs to wake up attached phones.

So I started with `priority=normal`, as I expected the behaviour explained here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
[image]

But what I actually observe is more like what is being described here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref
[image]

When I switch to `priority=high` messages arrive like instant indeed.

So it seems like the first piece of Firebase documentation is wrong? 
Or how do I need to proceed to achieve the behavior described there, cause that is, what I'd actually needed in my use case?

BTW I use `time_to_live=0` messages in such cases. Messages are small, less than 50 bytes of data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use priority= high like this for example:

```
const options = {
priority: "high",
timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
};
```

If you want instant notifications when device is in background or shutdown then you need to use `priority: "high"` since it means that the notification that is sent will have higher priority thus appearing instantly and waking the device.

> FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run some limited processing (including very limited network access). High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized.

timetolive:

> This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline. The maximum time to live supported is 4 weeks, and the default value is 4 weeks. For more information

Comment: But what I really need is: Deliver instantly to running apps, otherwise I'd like to avoid waking up the device.

Comment: you can use notification messages for that instead of data messages

Comment: I am afraid, I do not understand how your reply is connected to my question. This does of course not say, your reply might not be interesting for other people, but it is not an answer, is it?

Comment: i was explaining the priority since you said in the question that there is confusion, then in the comment you said you want it when it is running so i suggested using notifcation messages then

Comment: I quoted two pieces of documentation (one of which you quoted again) which do tell me different behaviour. I'd like to have the behaviour described in first quote, but experience the one in second. Question is, if there is some setup to get the behaviour described in the first piece of documentation.